# What happens once you build all possible types of a floor in LEGO Tower?

Tags: lego-tower

When building floors in LEGO Tower, you always get a random floor (from the selected type), but never one that you already have.

I was wondering what happens when you have built all the floors of one type (eg. food)? Will you get the same floors you already have, or will it be impossible to further build any floors of that type?

Answer (score 1):

I've continuously built floors of the same type to answer this question. Once you built all the floors of one type, the type will become disabled.

Here's a before/after screenshot. Once all different floors of the *Retail* type were built, the option became unavailable:

[image: LEGO Tower floor selection]